# tomcat apache+mysql connection in android

Tags: mysql, web-services, tomcat

Am developed one android application.Here i got following error in my tomcat console window:

```
Error - Unable to Connect to the Databasejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[ERROR] com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
at org.web.travel_ceylon.ws.Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.getLongitude_City(Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.java:30)
... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Connection
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
... 30 more
     Error - Unable to Connect to the Databasejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  [ERROR] com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
at org.web.travel_ceylon.ws.Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.getLatitude_City(Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.java:47)
... 29 more
    Error - Unable to Connect to the Databasejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    [ERROR] com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
at org.web.travel_ceylon.ws.Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.getLongitude_Im_Place(Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.java:64)
... 29 more
   Error - Unable to Connect to the Databasejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   [ERROR] com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
at org.web.travel_ceylon.ws.Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.getLatitude_Im_Place(Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.java:81)
... 29 more
    Error - Unable to Connect to the Databasejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   [ERROR] com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
at org.web.travel_ceylon.ws.Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.getCategory_Im_Place(Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.java:98)
... 29 more
   Error - Unable to Connect to the Databasejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 [ERROR] com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Connection
at org.web.travel_ceylon.ws.Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.getDescription_Im_Place(Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service.java:115)
... 29 more
```

My webservice coding part is:

```
package org.web.travel_ceylon.ws;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service {
private String url;
private Connection con;
private Statement stmt;

public void connectToDB() {
url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/travel_ceylon";
try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "");
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("Error - Unable to Connect to the Database" + e);

}
}

public float getLongitude_City(String city) {
connectToDB();
float lngt = 0;
try {
 stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt
 .executeQuery("SELECT Longitude FROM city WHERE City_Name='"
   + city + "'");
rs.next();
lngt = rs.getFloat("Longitude");
} catch (SQLException e) {
 System.out.println("Error - Unable to get longitude of " + city
 + " :" + e);
}
return lngt;
 }

public float getLatitude_City(String city) {
connectToDB();
float latt = 0;
try {
stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt
 .executeQuery("SELECT Latitude FROM city WHERE City_Name='"
   + city + "'");
  rs.next();
 latt = rs.getFloat("Latitude");
   } catch (SQLException e) {
   System.out.println("Error - Unable to get latitude of " + city
   + " :" + e);
   }
   return latt;
   }

   public float getLongitude_Im_Place(String place) {
  connectToDB();
float lngt = 0;
 try {
   stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = stmt
   .executeQuery("SELECT Longitude FROM important_places WHERE Place_Name='"
   + place + "'");
   rs.next();
 lngt = rs.getFloat("Longitude");
 } catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("Error - Unable to get longitude of " + place
 + " :" + e);
  }
 return lngt;
 }

  public float getLatitude_Im_Place(String place) {
  connectToDB();
  float latt = 0;
  try {
  stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt
 .executeQuery("SELECT Latitude FROM important_places WHERE Place_Name='"
   + place + "'");
  rs.next();
  latt = rs.getFloat("Latitude");
  } catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("Error - Unable to get latitude of " + place
 + " :" + e);
  }
  return latt;
  }

 public String getCategory_Im_Place(String place) {
  connectToDB();
  String cat = "";
  try {
  stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt
 .executeQuery("SELECT Category FROM important_places WHERE Place_Name='"
   + place + "'");
  rs.next();
  cat = rs.getString("Category");
   } catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println("Error - Unable to get  Category of " + place
 + " :" + e);
  }
 return cat;
 }

 public String getDescription_Im_Place(String place) {
 connectToDB();
 String des = "";
 try {
  stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt
 .executeQuery("SELECT Description FROM important_places WHERE Place_Name='"
   + place + "'");
 rs.next();
 des = rs.getString("Description");
 } catch (SQLException e) {
System.out.println("Error - Unable to get Description of " + place
 + " :" + e);
}
return des;
}
}
```

Dis is my  android application coding:

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCityLongitude"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCityLatitude"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIMLon"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIMLat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIMCat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtIMDes"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.web.frontend.calculator"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AndroidFrontendActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

 </manifest>
```

Dis is my AndroidFrontendActivity.java file:

```
package org.web.frontend.calculator;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidFrontendActivity extends Activity {

private String METHOD_NAME = "";
// our webservice method name
private String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.travel_ceylon.web.org";
// Here package name in webservice with reverse order.
private String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
// NAMESPACE + method name
private static final String URL = "http://10.0.0.55:8085/Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service  /services/Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service?wsdl";

// you must use ipaddress here, don’t use Hostname or localhost

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String city = "Matara";
    String im = "Galle Face";

    METHOD_NAME = "getLongitude_City";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("city", city);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCityLongitude)).setText(city
                + " Longitude is : " + result.toString());

    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCityLongitude)).setText("ERROR:"
                + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
    }
    METHOD_NAME = "getLatitude_City";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("city", city);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCityLatitude)).setText(city
                + " Latitude : " + result.toString());

    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCityLatitude)).setText("ERROR:"
                + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
    }

    METHOD_NAME = "getLongitude_Im_Place";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("place", im);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIMLon)).setText(im
                + " Longitude : " + result.toString());

    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIMLon)).setText("ERROR:"
                + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
    }

    METHOD_NAME = "getLatitude_Im_Place";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("place", im);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIMLat)).setText(im
                + " Latitude : " + result.toString());

    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIMLat)).setText("ERROR:"
                + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
    }

    METHOD_NAME = "getCategory_Im_Place";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("place", im);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object result = envelope.getResponse();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIMCat)).setText(im
                + " Category : " + result.toString());

    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIMCat)).setText("ERROR:"
                + E.getClass().getName() + ":" + E.getMessage());
    }

    METHOD_NAME = "getDescription_Im_Place";
    try {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("place", im);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.
```

Comment: *"Error - Unable to Connect to the Database java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"* - looks like you're missing the MySQL JDBC driver on your Tomcat server.

Comment: Hi i already add mysql connector jar file on my project...

Comment: am using to add following dis step:     right click of my project-->build path-->configure build path-->add external jar-->add mysql-connector-java-3.0.17.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the Connector/J JAR file into either Tomcat's `lib` directory (if you are using a container-provided DataSource) or into the webapp's `WEB-INF/lib` directory (if your webapp is managing all its own database connections.

Note that this has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: am using to add following dis step: right click of my project-->build path-->configure build path-->add external jar-->add mysql-connector-java-3.0.17.jar

Comment: If you can compile, the build path settings are ok.  If you can't run, need more info about how you deploy your Eclipse project to your app server is needed.  Also agreed that this has nothing to do with Android.

Comment: then how is connecting mysql database using soap webservices in android

Comment: Your SOAP service is connected to a MySQL database. It's just a coincidence that you are using an Android app to access the SOAP service.

Comment: Really it is useful and very helpful for me...thanks for ur help...thank u very much yar..

Answer (score 0):

If you adding library like this (project-->build path-->configure build path-->add external jar-->add mysql-connector-java-3.0.17.jar). It just consider while compling but at the time of export or run time it will not exported with project so for that just add this file into this file `project_folder\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib` as Christopher Schultz said manually and it will work .